# Change Workflow Notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, notifications

I want to make a combination between the workflow message and the notification message.. Here's what I mean:

I want this email text:
[image]

To be in the same email as the workflow notification:
[image]

I tried with SharePoint Designer and I found the workflow email, but i don't find the notification output.

In the workflow email you don't see the changes the other person did. The idea is, that you get **one** email from the workflow start with all the information that has been changed and a link to accept or decline it. Anyone have an idea about what I mean or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a combination like you would like to implement.
The notification output will handled by a completely different component and can be modified by following the links below.

To combine this is not possible in my opinion.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0/

Also, here is an interesting article to get a deeper dive into the background.
http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/08/26/the-truth-about-how-daily-sharepoint-alerts-actually-work.aspx

My recommendation is to handle all things in your workflow.

Hope this helps.